# CSS Grid content to stay in the grid area and not to flow out

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way for the grid areas to automatically adjust to the size of the content in them.

Right now I have used:
grid-auto-rows: min-content;

And

grid-auto-columns: min-content;

and thought that should fix the problem.

The image below shows how the content is not contained in the grid area.

[image]

```css
.container {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 20px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
        grid-auto-rows: min-content;
        grid-auto-columns: min-content;
      }
      
      
      
      :root {
  --yellow: #ffc600;
  --black: #272727;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: var(--black);

}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}



.item {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: var(--yellow); 
}

.item p {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="item item1">1kajhdkha</div>
      <div class="item item2">2aksdakj</div>
      <div class="item item3">as,jhdahfjhs,h3</div>
      <div class="item item4">4akshdasd</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? Should the items wrap to a new row?

Comment: For the grid area size to grow if the content/item inside it larger than the grid area.

Comment: take a look at CSS 'hyphens' https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_hyphens.asp - could be one of multiple solutions (in your case you would have to use '&shy;')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add Css

```
.item {
display: grid;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 35px;
background-color: var(--yellow);
word-break: break-all;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The grid properties should be given to the parent so that child can stay within the boundaries of the parent. Hence you have to put the content inside a `span` or `div` like this:

```
<div class="item item1"><span>1kajhdkh sdsd sdsa</span></div>
```

And add this to css for ".item" :

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: The word-break: break-all; worked without the need of the span

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:none` and `word-break:xxx` as you want in `.item` class.